# How to display information keyed in a form into a new page?

Tags: python, html, django, atom-editor

I am on page 1, I input a word into a form and hit submit after that I want to be taken to a new page and display information from a database table with the provided information as a key. How do I do that?

```
Below is the code that I tried.
VIEWS.PY file

def Professional_Development(request):
    resources=TheProfessionalResources.objects.order_by('Field')

    form=forms.FieldForm()
    user_dit={'user':resources,'form':form}


    if request.method=='POST':
        form=forms.FieldForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            variable=form.cleaned_data['name']
            print(variable)
            ace=TheProfessionalResources.objects.filter(Field=variable)
            resources=TheProfessionalResources.objects.order_by('Field')

            print("EXECUTING FORM")
            user_dict={'user':resources,'form':form,'ACE':ace,'VARIABLE':variable}
            return render(request,'first_app/Resources_Professional.html',context=user_dict)

    print("EXECUTKING PAGE")
    return render(request,'first_app/Professional_Development.html',context=user_dit)

2nd function in views.py file
def Resources_Professional(request):
    resources=TheProfessionalResources.objects.order_by('Field')


    form=TheProfessionalResourcesForm()
    user_dict={'user':resources,'form':form}
    return render(request,'first_app/Resources_Professional.html',context=user_dict)

HTML FILE
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% extends "first_app/basic_skeleton.html" %}

{%block body_block%}

<H1>Please sign up here</H1>
{%if user%}

     <ol>
      {%for person in user%}
      <li>{{person.Field}}</li>
     </ol>
     {%endfor%}
    {%endif%}

    <form method="post">

    {{form.as_p}}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="submit">

    </form>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <H1>Please sign up here</H1>
  {{VARIABLE}}
  {%if ACE%}

       <ol>
        {%for person in ACE%}
        <li>{{person.Title}}</li>
       </ol>
       {%endfor%}
      {%endif%}


 {{form.as_p}}
  </body>
</html>

URLS.PY in the project folder

from django.urls import path
from first_app import views
urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^basic_skeleton/',views.basic_skeleton,name='basic_skeleton'),
        url(r'^Professional_Development/',views.Professional_Development,name='Professional_Development'),
        url(r'^Personal_Development/',views.Personal_Development,name='Personal_Development'),
        url(r'^Financial_Development/',views.Financial_Development,name='Financial_Development'),

       url(r'^first_app/',include('first_app.url')),
       url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),
       url(r'^Resources_Professional/$',views.Resources_Professional,name='Resources_Professional'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

URLS .py file in applications folder

from django.conf.urls import url,include
from first_app import views

app_name='first_app'

urlpatterns=[
url(r'^$',views.basic_skeleton,name='basic_skeleton'),
url(r'^Personal_Development/$',views.Personal_Development,name='Personal_Development'),
url(r'^Financial_Development/$',views.Financial_Development,name='Financial_Development'),
url(r'^Professional_Development/$',views.Professional_Development,name='Professional_Development'),
url(r'^Resources_Professional/$',views.Resources_Professional,name='Resources_Professional'),


]
```

Or you could also help me create a list on page 1, and then upon clicking a link on page one, I need to be taken to page two with details related to that particular link and if some other link is clicked then details associated with the second link on page 2.

Please help, I am stuck at this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how the outline will work:

1. Create the form and get the data successfully (view 1)
2. Store the data into the database
3. Create a new view and pass the data as a context into another template (view 2)

For the implementation part, your code seems a bit messy. I will recommend using Django's default class-based views (Use one of the [edit views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/) for 1 and 2 and use [template view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#templateview) for 3) as you need to write a lot less things. If you insist on function-based views, I need more time to come up with an answer.

Comment: could u share possible implementation of clas based view or any reference links

Comment: The links are already included. In case you don't see it, [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/) will take you to EditViews (pick one to use, there are four and they have different purposes) and [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#templateview) will take you to templateview.

Comment: if multiple users visit  our  website then also will this approach work,actually i still have some course part left gto be completed so i dont know about these topics .

Comment: So then what you might do is to **bind whichever service you have to a user** so that each user can mind their own business without interfering with the others. To me, the best approach is to use some foreignkeys.

Comment: please tell me one more thing i just want to get details of a particular selected item what will be  agood apprach to hve peole enter the required info in a form and then give details regarding that or create clickable links and from there transfer tuser to details related to the links he clicked on ,which is simpler of tghese 2.

Comment: As you mentioned "display details", creating links that redirect to detail views is definitely easier as there is another Class-based view called DetailView ([link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview)) ready for you to use. Remember that you must pass in a primary key as a part of your URL because it redirects to a specific object.